# Why are there no 9.6 V AGM batteries?

Tags: batteries

I am trying to build a replacement battery pack for an older avionics tester. It has an 8 V AGM battery.

I can only find 6 V or 12 V AGM batteries.

8 V would do, but I cannot find any compact AGM 8 V battery packs.

In fact, I could not find anything in the 8 V range.

I can build what I need using separate 2 V cells.

I accept that 8V AGN batteries may not exist.

Question:

I would be interested in knowing if there is a technical reason for this being the case.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149381/discussion-on-question-by-juan-jimenez-why-are-there-no-9-6-v-agm-batteries); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AGM sealed lead acid batteries are available with the following voltages,
in addition to the commonly used 12 & 24 V.

2V - 2.5, 4.5, 5, 6, 8 Ah

4 V - 2.5, 5, 8 Ah

6 V - 2.5, 4.5, 5, 8 Ah

8 V - 2.5, 3.2, 5, 8 Ah.

More information over [here](https://www.batterystore.com/agm-sealed-lead-acid/).

Comment: Looks good. Do you have any links to information sources?

Comment: Hi Russel, Here's the link -  https://www.batterystore.com/agm-sealed-lead-acid/

Comment: That's an utterly superb resource. Not just as a place to buy (though there is that :-) ) but as a one stop site to see many of the many many many battery types available.  Could you please include the link in your answer. (I thought about adding it myself but resisted the urge :-) )

Comment: Thank you, Russel. Will certainly add the link in my answer.

Comment: I agree, excellent resource for researching the available battery configs. Thank you @vu2nan.

Comment: It looks like I should be using AA size cells, 16 per battery pack, two 8-cell groups, each group serial for 9.6v and then parallel the two groups. That would fit the required form factor and give me good capacity. NiCD or NiMH would do but the original charger is for NiCD. I think it would still work for NiMH. It applies 9.6v until current drops, and then goes into float mode. Anybody see anything stupid in this idea? 

Comment: @Juan Jimenez - Anytime, Juan!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the number of cells in series and the battery chemistry. For lead acid (AGM's are a lead acid chemistry) each cell is around 2V. Only multiples of cells can be manufactured, you can't have a 1/2 cell, the voltage is dependent on chemistry.

[image]

Source: https://footprinthero.com/lead-acid-battery-voltage-charts

Other chemistries also have integer multiples, li-ion is multiples of 3.7v